# Using uninitialized memory pointer in C

Tags: c, list, initialization, free, allocation

I am creating a general library for working with lists in C. I want to implement this method called destroy that will deallocate memory for this list by freeing each of its elements, but the compiler keeps giving me this warning, although everything works fine in a program that I made using this library:

Warning C6001   Using uninitialized memory '*pointer'.

How can I prevent this warning?

```
void destroy(list* first_elem)
{
    item* pointer = *first_elem;

    if (*first_elem == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    while (pointer->next != NULL) { //here's the warning
        item* toKill = pointer;
        pointer = pointer->next;
        free(toKill);
    }
    free(pointer);
    *first_elem = NULL;
}
```

Definitions of item and list:

```
typedef struct item_struct {
    Set value;
    struct item_struct* next;
} item;
```

```
typedef item* list;
```

Comment: Please post the exact complete and unedited test of the warning message. Include the definitions of `list` and `item` as well.

Comment: Instead of checking if `*first_elem == NULL`, try checking if `pointer == NULL`

Comment: It should be `while (pointer)`, because you don't check for `pointer` itself being NULL.

Comment: Edited the question including definitions of list and item and the complete warning message.

Comment: @DmitryBrant tried that, still gives me the warning.

Comment: @Cheatah tried that as well, same problem

Comment: Cannot reproduce this, what compiler version and compilation options are you using?

Comment: Do not hide pointer nature behind a typedef (your `list` type, for example).  It confuses much more than it help, except possibly when you mean the `typedef` type to be treated as an opaque one.

Comment: Is this a tooltip in Visual Studio?  This particular one has been known to give false positives.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you are creating item struct, you didn't initialize "item_struct *next" pointer.

```
item i;
i.value = ....;
i.next = NULL; // Add this into your code.
```

Using uninitialized variables is an undefined behaviour. Hence it can cause problems. Even if your code is running okey in your computer, this doesn't necessarily mean it will work another computer without an error.